# how do override app/etc/config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, core-config-data

Can i override app/etc/config.xml and put the core_cache_option table in a different schema from the other tables?

If so how?

EDITED:

I want the core_cache_option table to be in a different schema to the rest of the magento tables.

Comment: Not sure as to why you might want to do this ?

Comment: Magento reads **all** `xml` files in that directory in alphabetic order, combines them into one massive `xml` data structure. Last man standing wins and overrides.